# How to define functions on classes representing data structures to the integers

Tags: c++, function, templates, integer

I have a few classes which represent the data inside my system. I am looking for a generic method to define functions on them, for example given a class

```
class book
{
  private:
    std::string isbn;
    std::string title;
    std::string author;
}
```

I would like to be able to express functions such as

```
        | -1, if title == 'Wuthering*'
f(book)=|  0, otherwise
```

or

```
        | 100, if author == 'Douglas Adams'
f(book)=|  10, if author == 'D*'
        |   0, otherwise
```

I don't know what these functions are going to be in advance, but I will have to interpret strings to create them.

The goal is to allow the user to enter a string such as

```
book.author = 'Douglas Adams' -> 100; book.author = 'D*' -> 1;
```

and then sort a vector of books according to that score.

**Question**: Is there a standard pattern to be able to define such functions flexibly using templates?

Comment: So you want a function that maps conditions to values? Can you show what you're doing right now that is "not good enough" to make you ask this question?

Comment: What is the flexible part? Do you want those functions to work for other classes than book wich have the field title ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for me there is no need for templates

- create interface for assigning to book value
- implement it to calculate value by title, by author
- create class for sorting and use std::sort

  ```
  class Book
  {

  };

  class BookValue
  {
  public:
      virtual ~BookValue() {}
      virtual int value( const Book& book ) = 0;
  };

      class TitleValue : public BookValue
      {
       virtual int value( const Book& book ) { return 0; }
      };

  class AuthorValue : public BookValue
  {
      virtual int value( const Book& book ) { return 1; }
  };

  class Comparator
  {
  public:
  enum Mode
  {
      TitleMode, AuthorMode
  };

  Comparator( Mode mode )
  {
      if( TitleMode == mode )
      {
          bookValue = new TitleValue();
      }
      if( AuthorMode == mode )
      {
          bookValue = new AuthorValue();
      }
  }
  ~Comparator() { delete bookValue; }
  inline bool operator() (const Book& b1, const Book& b2)
  {
      return bookValue->value( b1 ) < bookValue->value( b2 );
  }
  private:
      BookValue* bookValue;
  };

  int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
  {
      Book b1;
      Book b2;
      std::vector< Book > v;
      v.push_back( b1 );
      v.push_back( b2 );
      std::sort( v.begin(), v.end(), Comparator( Comparator::TitleMode ) );
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

I would define a generic function taking a map of regex values and expected result for each one.

Here is an example (I used member functions, they can be moved outside the class but then you would need accessors for the attributes)

regex matching xcan be done using boost::regex.

```
class book
{
public:
    static int f( const std::map<std::string,int>& cond, int defaultRes, std::string& param )
    {
        for ( std::map<std::string,int>::const_iterator iter = cond.begin();
              iter != cond.end();
              ++iter )
        {
            if ( match( iter->first, param ) ) // a regex match function
                return iter->second;
        }
        return defaultRes;
    }

    int firstExample()
    {
        std::map<std::string,int> cond;
        cond["Wuthering*"] = -1;
        return f( cond, 0, title );
    }

    int secondExample()
    {
        std::map<std::string,int> cond;
        cond["Douglas Adams"] = 100;
        cond["D*"] = 10;
        return f( cond, 0, author );
    }
private:
    std::string isbn;
    std::string title;
    std::string author;
};
```

The `cond` map can easily be created by parsinf a string of pairs.